# Using kotlin scope function (cleanup)

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to implement the Kotlin scope function so assigning the variable like type/queue is clear to me but the `flush()` and `startTimer()` are not clear wheather I am using them correctly or not.

```kotlin
 @KotlinCleanup("use scope function")
        var c = note.cards()[0]
        c.type = CARD_TYPE_REV
        c.queue = QUEUE_TYPE_REV
        c.due = (col.sched.today - 8).toLong()
        c.factor = STARTING_FACTOR
        c.setReps(3)
        c.lapses = 1
        c.ivl = 100
        c.startTimer()
        c.flush()
```

Is this the correct way to use the scope function on this variable ?

```kotlin
       var c = note.cards()[0].apply {
            type = CARD_TYPE_REV
            queue = QUEUE_TYPE_REV
            due = (col.sched.today - 8).toLong()
            factor = STARTING_FACTOR
            setReps(3)
            lapses = 1
            ivl = 100
            startTimer()
            flush()
        }
```

Comment: Well, does it *work*? What are the requirements to be "correct"?

Comment: Yes, this looks right. Did you run into any issues that made you think this might not be the right solution? If so, what were they?

Comment: No, I didn't run into any problem or error but just wanted to make sure I am following the right convention @Sam